# Famo.us - triggering event and piping

Tags: events, eventtrigger, famo.us, piping

Let's say I have three Views. AppView, MenuView and StripView. MenuView contains multiple StripViews and AppView contains one MenuView. How can I trigger event from StripView and listen on that event on AppView.

***EDIT***

Let's say I want to click on ImageSurface on StripView and reigster that event on AppView, and then do some transitionig.

**MY SOLUTION**

**Everything is based on Timbre app, created in Famou.us Starter Kit Reference Tutorials**

// StripView.js (_setListeners() is called in StripView constructor and bodySurface is defined in code)

```
  function _setListeners() {


        var  eventScope =  this._eventOutput;

        this.backgroundSurface.on('click',function(){
           eventScope.emit('test', { somedata:'some value'} );


        }.bind(this));

}
```

// MenuView.js (_createStripViews() is called in MenuView constructor)

```
function _createStripViews() {
    this.stripModifiers = [];
    var yOffset = this.options.topOffset;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.stripData.length; i++) {
        var stripView = new StripView({
            iconUrl: this.options.stripData[i].iconUrl,
            title: this.options.stripData[i].title
        });
        var stripModifier = new StateModifier({
            transform: Transform.translate(0, yOffset, 0)
        });

        this.stripModifiers.push(stripModifier);

        this.add(stripModifier).add(stripView);

        yOffset += this.options.stripOffset;

        stripView.pipe(this._eventOutput);


    }
}
```

//AppView.js  (menuView is defined in code and _setListeners() is called in AppView constructor)

```
  function _setListeners() {

    this.menuView.on('test',function(){
      console.log("IT WORKS");
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use Views built in handlers to achieve this. These are _eventInput and _eventOutput.. Here is an example using an ImageSurface in StripView and responding to a click in AppView..

Hope it helps!

```
// In StripView.js

var imageSurface = new ImageSurface();

imageSurface.on('click',function(){
    this._eventOutput.trigger('image-click', { somedata:'some value'} );
}.bind(this));


// In AppView.js

var stripView  = new StripView();

this.subscribe(stripView);

this._eventInput.on('image-click',function(data){
    // Do Something
});
```

Comment: Can I use emit insted of trigger ?

Comment: My stripView is not defined in AppView, multiple stripViews are difined in MenuView, and one MenuView is defined in AppView. I am using some heavy programmed examples to work on. Not sure if I am ready for that level of programming.

Comment: I see you figured it out. There are many ways these events can be hooked up. No one way is always right! :)

Comment: I hope I have figured it out. Famo.us is not so easy for unexpirienced programmer but results are awesome. Your answer is right.

Comment: Yes, eventing is a more complicated topic that many programmers have experienced and are familiar with. Just takes time! You'll get there!